# how resolve error in groupby list

Tags: asp.net

I want someone to help how can i fiw the error in    `**list = g.ToList();**` when i add   `**var g = s.GroupBy(u => u.famille);**`  the error apperead when i add the **GROUPBY** can someone helpme how to fix it.
and this is the error message appeared when i ad the line grouby:**you cannot implicity convert type System.collections.Generic.list  >  to System.collections.Generic.list >**

```
public List<famille> Getlistfournisseur()
            {
                familleEntities db = new familleEntities();
                List<famille> list = new List<famille>();
                var s = db.famille.Where(x => x.famille!= "").OrderByDescending(x => x.famille);
                var g = s.GroupBy(u => u.article);
                list = g.ToList();
                return list;
            }
```

Comment: let me explain it this way, how do you expect the result to look like after you group it by. Your group by is conflicting with the output your requesting a group by is not a "Distinct"

Comment: sorry i make a mistake  var g = s.GroupBy(u => u.article);

Comment: i have to group by article because any famille have from 0 to n article

Comment: OK try this `s.GroupBy(u => u.article).Select( v=> v.//some property);`